# What influences whether Hoid can hide from a Shard?

Tags: cosmere

In the Cosmere novels, Hoid travels to a variety of planets, generally trying to avoid the notice of the gods (Shards) that tend to inhabit them, many of which would not mind seeing him dead or rendered harmless, and which have some capacity to perceive multiple events anywhere on their planets simultaneously.

Endowment mocks him for thinking that he could hide from her, while Harmony expresses surprise that Hoid could hide from him. By contrast, Hoid manages to hide from Odium (as Rayse) for a long time, but Odium (as Taravangian) notices him rather quickly.

The ability to notice Hoid is clearly not a question of power, since Harmony has two Shards, nor of unopposed influence over a planet, since whether Odium could detect Hoid seemed to depend on whether Rayse or Taravangian was holding the Shard.

What, then, makes some Shards or Vessels almost unable to notice Hoid, while others have less difficulty or none at all?

Comment: I guess we can also note the father machine as a very powerful entity that noticed Hoid nearly *immediately*, but since it is (a) not a Shard and (b) this occurs hundreds of years in the future, it's relevance is unclear.

Comment: Given his (lack of) history? Anything? RAFO? Dawnshard scarring? A really tight Coppercloud? Investiture kegels? Plain old staying under the "radar"?

Comment: I don't think there's a reason to think Taravangian "detected" him in the way Rayse couldn't. It's likely a specific effect that works identically for all shards, blocking a specific shard ability, but not other ways of finding him.